# How to upload image to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a `.jpg` image into a mysql table, but it's not working.

It displays the following error message:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

How to fix it?

This is my code:

```
<form action="image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `images` ( image,image_name) VALUES ( '$image', '$image_name')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}

?>
```

Comment: That warning is because each page load it's attempting to insert a record into the database even though nothing is posted. Wrap your PHP code in a `if (!empty($_FILE['image'])) { ... }` check.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should check if your image column is BLOB type!

I don't know anything about your SQL table, but if I'll try to make my own as an example.

We got fields id (int), image (blob) and image_name (varchar(64)).

So the code should look like this (assume ID is always '1' and let's use this mysql_query):

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_images` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}', '{$image_name}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```

You are doing it wrong in many ways. Don't use mysql functions - they are deprecated! Use PDO or MySQLi. You should also think about storing files locations on disk. Using MySQL for storing images is thought to be Bad Idea™. Handling SQL table with big data like images can be problematic.

Also your HTML form is out of standards. It should look like this:

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents method is not used to save the jpg image, it is used to read the contents of a file into a string. Because it will use memory mapping techniques, if this is supported by the server, to enhance performance. So, you should first create a folder into your root folder or any place inside the root folder wherever you want and then set the path to save the jpg image.

```
                    <?php
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
      if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
      } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
          echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            $file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $file_name);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $file_name;
          $sql = "INSERT INTO images ( image,image_name) VALUES ( '$image', '$file_name')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
                echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
            }
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo "Invalid file";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i try to insert jpg image. but it's display Invalid file

Comment: Please replace $_FILES["file"] with $_FILES["image"] because your field name is image.So please use print_r($_FILES) and here you can find your whole data and use it.

Comment: CAn you tell me that whats the error message ? and please first use print_r($_FILES);die; and then find that you are getting your fields or not.

Comment: i have uploaded jpg image.but it's alway print else part in bottom of the code. echo "Invalid file";

Answer (score 0):

Check The code below:

---HTML---

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
Image: <input type="file" name="photo">
<br>  
<input type="submit" value="Add">  
</form>
```

-- PHP --

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved  
$target = "images/";  
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);   
//This gets all the other information from the form  
$image_name=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']));
$image = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));   
// Connects to your Database  
mysql_connect("YOUR_HOST", "USERNAME", "PSSWORD") or die(mysql_error()) ;  
mysql_select_db("YOUR_DATABASE") or die(mysql_error()) ;   
//Writes the information to the database  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `product_images` VALUES ('', '$image', '$image_name')") ;   
//Writes the photo to the server  
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))  {   
//Tells you if its all ok  
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  
} else {   
//Gives and error if its not  
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";  }  
?>
```

Comment: It's display Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test\image.php on line 12

Comment: Be sure if you have created the folder images/!